# nth:child(1) return no element, nth-child(2) return the first element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got a weird problem. I use nth-child with my jQuery and right now when I use element:**nth-child(1) I get no response**, **when I use element:first I do get the element**, moreover **when I use element:nth-child(2) I get the *first* element**. like there is a mysterious element which I am not able to see, hope someone here could figure it out.

html:

```
<section id="portfolio">
      <h1>My Projects</h1>
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="arrow"><span class="left-arrow"></span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="app">
          <div class="image"><img src="./images/movies.jpg" alt="" /></div>
          <ul>
            <li><span> Name: </span> Movies WebApp</li>
            <li><span>Description:</span> Manage movise stock</li>
            <li><span>Backend:</span> -</li>
            <li><span>Frontend:</span> Angular, CSS, Html</li>
            <li><span>DB:</span> -</li>
            <li><span>link:</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="app">
          <div class="image"><img src="./images/coupon.jpg" alt="" /></div>
          <ul>
            <li><span> Name: </span> Movies WebApp</li>
            <li><span>Description:</span> Manage movise stock</li>
            <li><span>Backend:</span> -</li>
            <li><span>Frontend:</span> Angular, CSS, Html</li>
            <li><span>DB:</span> -</li>
            <li><span>link:</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
          <div class="arrow"><span class="right-arrow"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ol class="pagination"></ol>
    </section>
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var itemsLength = $('.app').length;
  console.log('for first:  ', $('.app:first'));
  console.log('for nth-child(1):  ', $('.app:nth-child(1)'));
  console.log('for nth-child(2):  ', $('.app:nth-child(2)'));
  console.log('app elements length: ', itemsLength);
  var position = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
    $('.pagination').append('<li><span class="fas fa-circle"></span></li>');
  }
  $('.app').hide();
  $('.app:first').show();
  $('.pagination li:nth-child(1)').css('color', '#4d4d4d');
```

output:
[image]

As you can see I get same the log for nth-child(2) and first, and different logs for nth-child(1) and first.
what cause that?

Note: I already saw similar problems to mine but not exactly, nothing which showed the different between nth-child to first. Therefor this is not a duplicate

Comment: You might want to use `$('.app').get(0)` to get first `.app` and `$('.app').get(1)` to get second `.app` and so on...

Comment: don't confuse CSS selector and jQuery selector ... what you need cannot be done with CSS, so use jQuery feature for that ... *Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification* https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: Try `$('.pagination').find(li:nth-child(1)').css('color', '#4d4d4d');`

Comment: I think you don't understand what `nth-child` does. It gets the element that is the nth child, not necessarily the nth element that matches that selector. So there is a first child, it is the `<div class="left"></div>` element. Therefore, the first element that matches `.app` is the second child. If you want the first element that matches `.app`, use `$('.app:eq(0)')` or `$('.app').eq(0)` or `$('.app').get(0)`

Comment: when I try to use $('.app').get(0).show() I get an error that .show is not a function @soktinpk

Comment: @hindi1991 yes if you want to use jquery functions you should use `.eq(0)`. Use `.get(0)` if you want the raw element (not jquery)

Comment: works great that a lot @soktinpk